# Как оптимизировать CLS (Google Page Speed)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagespeed-insights

Есть несколько страниц, где никудышный показатель CLS в Google Page Speed. Контент на страницах - текст, изображение, много текста. Изображения на разных страницах могут быть разного разрешения. Кроме того, ширина блока контента может быть разной на разных устройствах - сайт адаптивный. Картинке прописан css - `width: 100%; height: auto`. После окончания загрузки все выглядит отлично и работает.
Но рендерятся страницы так - сначала выводится все текст, потом загружается картинка и текст который ниже ее скачкообразно сдвигается вниз. Page Speed'у конечно такое дело не нравится.
Пока не придумал ничего лучше, чем резервировать место под изображение с помощью js, который придется корректировать под каждое изображение, т.к. они разного размера.

```
var pfwidth = document.querySelector('.p-first').offsetWidth; // Определяем доступный размер контейнера
var picf = document.querySelector('.pic-first');
picf.style.width = pfwidth + 'px'; // 1200
picf.style.height = pfwidth / 2 + 'px'; // 600
```

Можно что-то получше и более универсальное придумать?

Comment: Использовать картинки одинакового оазмера

Comment: @AlexeyTen почти нереально. Тут будет много часов работы дизайнера.

Comment: Ну выбирайте, или дизайнер или вы. Или забить на pagespeed